# How to safely handle "\n" with sed on automated scripts where "\n" can be in the input to these scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a shell script that is called via parameters (it's called by an external binary programm which I can not change), like this:

```
myscript.sh "param1" "param2"
```

Now, in this script there's a `sed "s/param1/param2/"`-like command involved and the `param2` can contain literaly the newline escape sequence `\n` (like `line1\nline2`):

```
VAL=$(echo "$2" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')
sed -i "s/$1/$VAL/" /a/path/to/file
```

I already did this: [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern) to escape backslashes and ampersands that may occur, but this does not help handling the newline `\n` (`sed` ignores it).

I know how to do it manually in a script (by entering a real newline, pressing Return, in the shell script file at the according place or do some stuff like `$(echo)`), but I have no influence to the parameters that are passed.

How can I safely handle the newline sequence so that sed does its job and inserts a newline when `\n` occurs in the parameter?

Comment: How do you pass the parameter to sed? I did a quick test and for me no escaping is required. The script contains only on line `echo abcdefg | sed "s/$1/$2/"`. I called it like this `./script.sh "d" "\ntest\n"` which results in three lines as expected `abc`, `test`, and `efg`.

Comment: @RamboRamon I added the real part of the script to the question.

Comment: You're replacing `\n` with `\\n`.

Comment: The `echo` seems to break it. If i do `echo "a\nb\nc"` I get three lines. Try invoking it with `-E` to suppress the interpretation.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath How can I ignore `\n` when doing "\ -> \\"?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would very strongly recommend replacing `sed` with `perl`. If you are able to do that, then your script becomes:

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN {$a=shift;$b=shift} s/$a/$b/' "$1" "$2" /a/path/to/file
```

You no longer need the `VAL` variable at all!

If for some bizarre reason you're absolutely restricted to `sed`, change the `VAL=` statement to:

```
VAL=$(echo "$2" | sed -ne '1h;2,$H;$x;$s/[\/&]/\\&/g;$s/\n/\\n/g;$p;')
```

But don't do that. Use the `perl` version instead.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\n` with real newlines:

```
VAL=${VAL//\\n/$'\n'}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021), a generic string substitution tool that works with arbitrary literals (neither newlines nor regexp characters being special) using `awk`:

```
# usage: gsub_literal STR REP
# replaces all instances of STR with REP. reads from stdin and writes to stdout.
gsub_literal() {
  # STR cannot be empty
  [[ $1 ]] || return

  # string manip needed to escape '\'s, so awk doesn't expand '\n' and such
  awk -v str="${1//\\/\\\\}" -v rep="${2//\\/\\\\}" '
    # get the length of the search string
    BEGIN {
      len = length(str);
    }

    {
      # empty the output string
      out = "";

      # continue looping while the search string is in the line
      while (i = index($0, str)) {
        # append everything up to the search string, and the replacement string
        out = out substr($0, 1, i-1) rep;

        # remove everything up to and including the first instance of the
        # search string from the line
        $0 = substr($0, i + len);
      }

      # append whatever is left
      out = out $0;

      print out;
    }
  '
}
```

Granted, that's a mouthful, but it's trivial to use:

```
gsub_literal "$1" "$val" <infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> VAL=$(echo "$2" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g')
> ```
>
> How can I safely handle the newline sequence so that sed does its job and inserts a newline
>   when `\n` occurs in the parameter?

You can just let `sed` undo the escaping of `\n` by adding `s/\\n/\n/g`, i. e.

```
 VAL=$(echo "$2" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g;s/\\n/\n/g')
```

Test:

```
# set a 'line1\nline2'
# VAL=$(echo "$2" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g;s/\\n/\n/g')
# sed "s/$1/$VAL/" <<<qay
qline1
line2y
```